# MS Excel how to create a macro to find duplicates and highlight them?

Tags: excel

How can I create a macro in MS excel to find duplicates in a spreadsheet and highlight it

Comment: duplicate rows, columns, values, formulae, can you please be a lot more specific ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a VBA macro. You can just use conditional formatting. Microsoft explain how to do exactly what you seem to need here:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HA011366161033.aspx

If you really need a macro, the easiest way would be to record the steps described above, then edit as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this snippet is useful:

```
Public Sub MarkDuplicates()
Dim iWarnColor As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Dim rngCell As Variant


Set rng = Range("A1:A200") ' area to check '
iWarnColor = xlThemeColorAccent2

For Each rngCell In rng.Cells
    vVal = rngCell.Text
    If (WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, vVal) = 1) Then
        rngCell.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
    Else
        rngCell.Interior.ColorIndex = iWarnColor
    End If
Next rngCell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub MarkDuplicates2()
Dim rngCell As Variant
Dim flag As Integer

Dim LastRow As Long

'To Check Duplicate records for dynamic rows:
    LastRow = 0
    With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

flag = 0`enter code here`
'Cell(2,2) represent "B2"
Set rng = Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(LastRow, 2))
iWarnColor = xlThemeColorAccent2

For Each rngCell In rng.Cells
    vVal = rngCell.Text
    If (WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, vVal) = 1) Then
        rngCell.Interior.Pattern = xlNone

    Else
        rngCell.Interior.ColorIndex = iWarnColor
        flag = flag + 1
    End If
Next rngCell

    If flag > 0 Then
    MsgBox flag & " cells (in light blue) contain an error.  Please Check!"
    Else
    MsgBox " Data Validation completed. No errors found."
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim Counter As Integer

    For Counter = 1 To 35

        'Cells.(X,Y) X = number, Y = Letter i.e D5 Cells(5,4)
        firstValue = ActiveSheet.Cells(Counter, 3)
        SecondValue = ActiveSheet.Cells(Counter, 4)

        If firstValue = SecondValue Then
            Rows(Counter).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 10, 10)
        End If


    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Ross Larson answered this question here: [Finding duplicate rows in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143396/finding-duplicate-rows-in-excel?rq=1)

Quoting from his answer, "The absolute fastest and easiest way. Conditional formatting, highlight duplicates (on the ID column). Then filter the column (presumably in a table) by the coloring (above the check boxes)."

Yesterday, I personally tried this out and it worked great. No need to write a macro or fancy VBA script. Just use the Excel out-of-the-box functionality.

The answer Paul Rayner gave in 2010 has a broken link. The Ross Larson link is still working - at least for now.

Comment: @avgvstvs I put in this answer for your edification ;)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.