# Finding duplicate rows in excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel spreadsheet with two rows. One is for name, and the other is for id. Is there any way i can find the rows that have the exact same id and allow me to easily see those? For example i have the rows:

```
Name:     Id
Hello     1
World     5
Mylo      1
Jack      6
Jil       9
Frank     5
```

So in the above example data, excel should somehow mark the rows with hello and mylo and world and frank to indicate that there are duplicate id's for those

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The absolute fastest and easiest way. Conditional formatting, highlight duplicates (on the ID column). Then filter the column (presumably in a table) by the coloring (above the check boxes).

Comment: On the Home Tab ribbon, click on the following: "Conditional Formatting", "Highlight Cells Rules", "Duplicate Values..."

Comment: @Solburn Your comment should be an answer.

Comment: @Solburn It cannot be right answer because it just highlight duplicated in one column not the rows

Answer (score 13):

In the third column you could add this formula (cell B3 example) :

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B$2:B$7,"="&B2)>1,"<--Dup!","")
```

You will have to adjust the range `B$2:B$7` to reflect the actual data range...

Comment: Works great. And if you only want to know the count of occurrences, use just COUNTIF(B$2:B$7,"="&B2).

Comment: Is it possible to do it on multiple columns instead of just one?