# Check if two rows are the EXACT SAME in MS Excel

Tags: excel

In MS Excel, what is the best way to see if two rows are the exact same? I've tried with conditional formatting but it only seems like I can only check for duplicat CELLS and not whole rows. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I think you'd need to provide a bit of information. How many columns are in the row? Do the number of columns in the row remain the same? Are the rows on the same sheet/workbook?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding duplicate rows in excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143396/finding-duplicate-rows-in-excel)

Comment: That's not a duplicate, even though the title makes it seem likely. That question is about finding duplicate values in a column, not duplicate rows.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need an array formula that compares the 2 rows.

If you want to find out if rows 1 and 2 are exactly the same, enter this formula in a cell that isn't in row 1 or 2:

```
=AND(EXACT(1:1,2:2))
```

Instead of pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing the formula, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, which will tell Excel you want an Array formula.

The result will be TRUE if they match and FALSE if they don't. You'll see curly braces around your formula if you've correctly entered it as an array formula.

Note that the EXACT formula will perform a case-sensitive comparison. Omit it if you want a case-insensitive comparison:

```
=AND(1:1=2:2)
```

entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> as well.

One last thing: if you want to check part of a row instead of the whole row, simply specify that in the formula.

```
=AND(EXACT(A1:E1,A2:E2))
```

entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, of course.

Answer (score 1):

you can use conditional formatting using a formula like

```
=or(and($A2:$E2=$A1:$E1),and($A2:$E2=$A3:$E3))
```

applied to row 2 and below. change the columns to suit

Comment: This approach worked for me while the other comment's suggestions gave me inconsistent results. I'm not sure why, though. First I tried `{=RC1:RC20=R[1]C1:R[1]C20}`, then `{=AND(RC1:RC20,R[1]C1:R[1]C20)}`. Neither of those provided the expected outcome. They appeared to be checking the first cell of the row. This answer looks like it should be wrong because it's not a standard usage of `AND`, but it worked correctly.