# How to add a excel file to javascript

Tags: javascript, html, excel

This is the code I have written, but it's lagging, is there any way to add all these numbers into a doc and import that to here also check for duplicate numbers.

```
var arr = [167667,
 380806,
 70539,
 795403,
 334282,
 501444,
 160053,
 20337,
 528241,
 939581,
 122592,
 908213,
 583233,
 690953,
 902610,
 261058,
 68789,
 580404,
 310895,
 36287,
 976648,
 781300,
 733446,
 766072,
 107201,
 181967,
 766037,
 36493,
 346505,
 433682,
 823326,
 399658,
 369109,
 636834,
 117927,
 596464,
 712822,
 618043,
 186489,
 411844,
 895102,
 994200,
 104045,
 749025,
 95403,
 767701,
 459858,
 190300,
 343644,
 899856,
 442547,
 504653,
 274322,
 396365,
 832169,
 988712,
 456936,
 15754,
 966000,
 420857,
 152327,
 679561,
 627742,
 378671,
 293522,
 258162,
 41711,
 845353,
 569123,
 575341,
 419077,
 88518,
 11712,
 710494,
 532277,
 358260,
 433693,
 558089,
 187393,
 262252,
 169450,
 693771,
 888835,
 559467,
 488718,
 665483,
 798311,
 441854,
 421367,
 950455,];
var sorted_arr = arr.sort(); // You can define the comparing function here. 
                             // JS by default uses a crappy string compare.
var results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    if (sorted_arr[i + 1] != sorted_arr[i]) {
        results.push(sorted_arr[i]);
    }
}

alert(results);
```

I have a file with lot of numbers.

I want to find out duplicate numbers from that,
instead of adding these numbers into array, is it possible to import that file here and check for duplicates.

This is the code I have written, but it's lagging, is there any way to add all these numbers into a doc and import that to here and check for duplicate numbers.
    please help it out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding duplicate rows in excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143396/finding-duplicate-rows-in-excel)

Comment: Thank you so much Jay, but i have such a huge data, and it is impossible to give id, names to them

Comment: is there any possible way to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can change the code that finds unique values to this:

```
var results = arr.filter(function(value, index, self){
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
});
```

But i don't know how much faster it is

Comment: where should i load file here

Comment: @manvitha This does not show you how to load from a file, but a possible way to optimize your code.