# error 91 object variable or with block variable not set on range

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

I'm new to VBA as was trying to write a macro that finds duplicates in different columns from a worksheet. I found the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2165356) helpful. However this solved it only for one column. So to add a few more columns I altered the code as follows

```
        Sub test()
    Dim iWarnColor As Integer
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rngCell As Variant
    Dim iWarnColor1 As Integer
    Dim rnga As Range
    Dim rngCell1 As Variant


    Set rng = Range("A1:A17") ' area to check '
    iWarnColor = xlThemeColorAccent2

    For Each rngCell In rng.Cells
        vVal = rngCell.Text
        If (WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, vVal) = 1) Then
            rngCell.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
        Else
            rngCell.Interior.ColorIndex = iWarnColor
        End If
    Next rngCell

    Set rnga = Range("B1:B17") ' area to check '
    iWarnColor1 = xlThemeColorAccent3

    For Each rngCell1 In rnga.Cells
        vVal = rngCell1.Text
        If (WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rnga, vVal) = 1) Then
            rngCell1.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
        Else
            rngCell1.Interior.ColorIndex = iWarnColor1
        End If
    Next rngCell1
    End Sub
```

On running this code I get 
    "Run time error 91: object variable or with block variable not set "

It says the error is at

```
For Each rngCell1 In rnga.Cells
```

What am I doing wrong here??

Comment: I can run your code locally in Excel 2010 without any errors, so not sure. Perhaps try to change the type of `rngCell1` from `Variant` to `Range` and see if it makes any difference. Also, `vVal` has not been `Dim`ed. It will only complain if you add `Option Explicit` at the top of your module, so it shouldn't matter here.

Comment: Thanks a lot, changing from `Variant` to `Range` fixed the problem. I too am using excel 2010 btw

Comment: Hmm, weird. At least I'm glad it's working for you now, which is the main thing. Do you want me to format my comment into a proper answer?

Comment: Yeaa that way I can accept it as an official answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can run your code locally in Excel 2010 without any errors, so not sure exactly what the problem is.

Try to change the type of `rngCell1` from `Variant` to `Range` and see if it makes any difference.

As a side note, `vVal` has not been `Dim`ed. It will only complain if you add `Option Explicit` at the top of your module, so it shouldn't matter here.