# Highlight Duplicates Matching Next Column

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

Would like to compare values of current day with previous day and highlight duplicates values for each item row-wise, my data has several rows and I have macros which imports data from text file everyday.
Test Data:

[image]

Here is the code I'm trying:

Sub Duplicates()

```
Dim refRng As Range, cell As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set refRng = .Range("B2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants)
    For Each cell In .Range("C2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants)
        If cell.value <> 0 Then
            If Not refRng.Find(what:=cell.value, LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False) Is Nothing Then cell.Interior.color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        End If
    Next cell
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Comment: Update your question with the current state of your coding project. If you don't tell us your exact problem, we can't give you an exact solution. For a general guideline to your general question, see my answer below.

Comment: [Here is a similar question maybe you can find the answer here ! =)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162684/ms-excel-how-to-create-a-macro-to-find-duplicates-and-highlight-them)

Comment: Updated question with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code to achieve the result. Following code will start from column B to column D.Change your range columns accordingly.

```
Dim cell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    'starts with Column C and matches C with B, D with C and so on..
    For Each cell In .Range("C2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants)
        'cell.Cells(1, 0) will refer previous cell
        If cell.Value = cell.Cells(1, 0) Then
            cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
            cell.Cells(1, 0).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        End If
    Next cell
End With
```

Comment: This worked `Sheets("Sheet1").Select
For i = 1 To 10

If Range("B" & i).Value = Range("C" & i).Value And Range("B" & i).Value <> "" Then
Range("B" & i).Select
   With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

Range("C" & i).Select
   With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End If
Next i
`

Answer (score 0):

For each pair [count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-count-property-excel) the occurences of each value. If it occures more than once, [color](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/colorindex-property) it.

Edit: Compare two adjacent values, If they match, color them in.

Comment: You are right, limiting it to only adjacent values simplifies it even further. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Conditional Formatting. Select the columns you want to compare then:

**Conditional Formatting > Highlight Cell Rules > Duplicate Values**

Comment: That does not work as it highlights everything which are common in selected range and I need to compare row wise.

Comment: You can also select rows to compare with. But yeah, I see what you're trying to do